# Algorithm to convert drawing of lines into polygons

Tags: algorithm, javafx, graphics, graphics2d

I have an export of a 2D model where everything is a line. Not all of the lines end at convenient intersecting corners, and some lines are actually several small ones to mimic a curve. For my purposes a straight line or multiple lines instead of a curve is fine.

What sort of algorithm should I look into so that I can create a list of Polygons instead of Lines that represent the same model.

In the image below, essentially I need to turn all the lines in the top image into polygons enclosing a single space as in the bottom image - but at a larger scale

[image: Essentially I need to turn all the lines at the to into polygons enclosing a single space - but at a larger scale]

Comment: I think first steps can be: 1. look for  an intersection that is shared by two edges (line) only (for example top-left corner of the posted image). 2. add these 2 edges to make a segment 3. if the other end of each edge is linked to one additional edge  only, add this edge to the segment.  4. continue to add edges until both ends of the segments are intersections of more than 2 edges. 5. Repeat 1-4 to form new segments, until all intersections of 2 edges only are included in segments.